fopen() con una ruta absoluta "c:\reporte resumen\reporte.csv" funciona perfecto en localhost pero cuando subo mi proyecto a mi Host no funciona
fopen() con una ruta absoluta c:\reporte resumen\reporte.csv funciona perfecto en localhost; pero cuando subo mi proyecto a mi Host; Sí me lo genera, pero en la ruta donde se encuentra mi proyecto y yo quiero que lo genere en la ruta c:\reporte resumen\reporte.csv del equipo del usuario visitante.
¿Hay alguna consideración que me falte para lograrlo?, ¿Es tema del Host?
Mi código es este:
$micarpeta = "c:\\reporte resumen";
$filename = $micarpeta."\\reporte.csv";
$archivo_csv = fopen($filename, 'w');
$linea = array("Reporte Resumen"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ");
fputcsv($archivo_csv, $linea, ",");
fclose($archivo_csv);


A ver a ver de nuevo... desde un servidor, quieres usar fopen para una ruta en el pc del usuario?

Y eso es C, PHP o qué?

Lo normal es generar el archivo en el servidor y luego darle al usuario la opción de "download", para que lo guarde en algún lugar de su elección.

¿Cómo funcionaría el código si el usuario accede a la página desde Linux (no hay disco C:), o desde un smartphone (no tienen disco)?

Por no hablar de que si yo accedo a tu página y me pides permiso para tocar C: la voy a cerrar y voy a buscar el email del dueño para ir a darle una visita. Ni loco le daría permiso a una web para acceder directamente a mi disco duro.... la seguridad de los navegadores y el sandbox en el que se ejecutan existe por algo.

La respuesta simple: NO SE PUEDE. Saludos

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Gracias por tus comentarios entiendo el tema de la seguridad; la confusión es por que en mi localhost si accede a la unidad c: del usuario visitante.

No se puede. Funciona así por razones de seguridad, para evitar que una página cualquier plante virus/malware en el equipo del usuario.
La solución es generar el archivo en el servidor y luego dar un link al usuario para que pueda descargarlo en su propio equipo, en la ubicación de su conveniencia.

Muchas Gracias por la solución y entiendo que es por razones de seguridad que no es posible. Mi confusión es por que en localhost si se puede.
